# How to integrate Api Gateway and Step Fucnctions in CDK?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

I have a statemachine.

```
        const task1 = new sfn.Task(this, 'Assign Case', {
            task: new tasks.InvokeFunction(Lambda1),
        });

        const task2 = new sfn.Task(this, 'Close Case', {
            task: new tasks.InvokeFunction(Lambda2),
        });

        const chain = sfn.Chain.start(task1)
            .next(task2);

      const StateMachine = new sfn.StateMachine(this, `StateMachine`, {
            definition: chain
        });
```

And I need to call this statemachine from Api-gateway resource.I have used the below code and it throws an error like 'statemacine is not assignable to paramaeter of type AwsIntegrationProps'

```
 const resource = this.api.root.addResource(path);
 resource.addMethod(method, new apigw.AwsIntegration(handler), { apiKeyRequired: true }); 
 //handler is above statemachine
```

My api gateway integration request looks like this in console.

[image]

Comment: did you get it to work by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `apigateway.LambdaIntegration` which extends AwsIntegration.

```js
export declare class LambdaIntegration extends AwsIntegration {
    private readonly handler;
    private readonly enableTest;
    constructor(handler: lambda.IFunction, options?: LambdaIntegrationOptions);
    bind(method: Method): void;
}
```

For example :

```js
const getBookIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(getBookHandler);
```

Later, use the `lambdaIntegration` when creating a new method:

```js
book.addMethod('GET', getBookIntegration);
```

More about [LambdaIntegration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html).

Answer (score 1):

The error 'statemacine is not assignable to paramaeter of type AwsIntegrationProps' is referring to you instantiation.

The [`AwsIntegration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.AwsIntegration.html) class takes an [`AwsIntegrationProps`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.AwsIntegrationProps.html) struct as input.

```
new AwsIntegration(props: AwsIntegrationProps)
```

Getting API Gateway to kickoff Step Functions directly is a little strange. I found this [Creating a Step Functions API Using API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html#api-gateway-test-api) tutorial helpful. The State Machine ARN is passed in the request body of the call, so you need to pass a request template if you don't want to require the user to specify the State Machine.

```
resource.addMethod(
    method,
    new apigw.AwsIntegration({
        handler: 'states',
        action: 'StartExecution',
        options: {
            requestTemplates: {
                'application/json': `{
                    "stateMachineArn": "${handler.ref}",
                    "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)"
                }`
            },
        },
    }),
    { apiKeyRequired: true }
);
```

(Note: I'm translating my code from Python so I'm not 100% on the strings in TypeScript.)

I also filled in credentialsRole, passthroughBehavior, and integrationResponses to the options to get mine setup the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

check here:
[api to state](https://medium.com/life-at-apollo-division/aws-cdk-execute-stepfunction-via-api-gateway-597b5c9e0b9f)

and here:

[state machine](https://sbstjn.com/blog/aws-cdk-state-machine-step-functions-lambda/)